# Setting Headers to Http Requests using Services in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to make a get request from this service as follows:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class AccountsService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  public httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('abc:xys')
    })
  }

  private accountsUrl = 'http://semsem.talaween.net/semsem/api/v1/users/';


  getAccounts(){
      return this.http.get('http://semsem.talaween.net/semsem/api/v1/users/', this.httpOptions);
      //console.log('here we are');
  }

}
```

I need to pass in the authorization key to the request in order to be able to access the API. If I include the this.httpOptions parameter from the get request inside the getAccounts() function, I receive a 404 not found error (Although I am certain there's noting wrong with the URL, as it returns data if I try with postman). If I take out the this.httpOptions parameter, I receive a 401 not authorized error, which I suppose makes sense as I am not passing the Authorization key. I can't seem to find the right syntax in the documentation to send the auth key along with my GET request. What is the right way of writing this GET request, containing the required Authorization key ?

Comment: You need to check or add CORS settings to your backend.